# Using CONTAINS in TableAdapter

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE CONTAINS(Description, @Description)
```

I am adding this query in TableAdapter using Visual Studio. It returns this error "The @Description SQL construct or statement is not supported".
Please, how do I go about making this query work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE Description like %@Description%
```